# Regular Expression to match Arabic or English Name

Tags: php, regex, arabic

I wanted a regular expression that would match Arabic OR English Names that would allow only characters(alphabets) and spaces, I found a JavaScript RegEx that does the job

```
var regex = /^(?:[a-zA-Z\s\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u08A0-\u08FF\uFB50-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF]|(?:\uD802[\uDE60-\uDE9F]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDEFF])){0,30}$/;
```

I converted it to PCRE compliant as

```
/^(?:[a-zA-Z\s\x{600}-\x{6FF}\x{750}-\x{77F}\x{8A0}-\x{8FF}\x{FB50}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FDFF}\x{FE70}-\x{FEFF}]|(?:\x{D802}[\x{DE60}-\x{DE9F}]|\x{D83B}[\x{DE00}-\x{DEFF}])){0,70}$/u
```

however when I try

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^(?:[a-zA-Z\s\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\x{0750}-\x{077F}\x{08A0}-\x{08FF}\x{FB50}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FDFF}\x{FE70}-\x{FEFF}]|(?:\x{D802}[\x{DE60}-\x{DE9F}]|\x{D83B}[\x{DE00}-\x{DEFF}])){0,70}$/u', 'Foo Bar'));
```

OR

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^(?:[a-zA-Z\s\x{600}-\x{6FF}\x{750}-\x{77F}\x{8A0}-\x{8FF}\x{FB50}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FDFF}\x{FE70}-\x{FEFF}]|(?:\x{D802}[\x{DE60}-\x{DE9F}]|\x{D83B}[\x{DE00}-\x{DEFF}])){0,70}$/u', 'Foo Bar'));
```

it returns

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: disallowed Unicode code point (>= 0xd800 && <= 0xdfff) at offset 127 in php shell code on line 1
>   bool(false)

Please help to resolve this warning!

Any help appreciated!
Thank You!

Comment: Why not only `\p{Arabic}`?

Comment: Replace `(?:\uD802[\uDE60-\uDE9F]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDEFF])` with `[\x{10A60}-\x{10A9F}\x{1EE00}-\x{1EEFF}]`, and the expression will look like [`/^[a-zA-Z\s\x{600}-\x{6FF}\x{750}-\x{77F}\x{8A0}-\x{8FF}\x{FB50}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FDFF}\x{FE70}-\x{FEFF}\x{10A60}-\x{10A9F}\x{1EE00}-\x{1EEFF}]{0,70}$/u`](https://regex101.com/r/CkX6Fn/1)

Comment: @revo : You meant [a-zA-Z\s\p{Arabic}] ?

Comment: To include English letters, yes. You may want to see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by letters you mean language main 28 characters you don't even have to construct a code-point based character class (you can build it by typing letters manually!).

But if you mean `Arabic` (`0600`–`06FF`, **255** characters) then again that long character class doesn't provide what you desire.

Anyhow you can go with this:

```
/^(?!.*\d)[a-z\p{Arabic}\s]+$/iu
```

Note: you may want to check for different blocks in Arabic script [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode).